# i want to compare json value(which is date) to my mobile phone(current date). 1st of the month and 16th of the month

Tags: android, mysql, json, date, datetime

I want to compare a JSON value (which is a date) to the data on my mobile phone (current date).
Actually my JSON contains only TWO date of a month I., 1st date and 16th date of a month. Now I want to show latest date from the JSON which is much closer the mobile phone date i.e. if date lies from 1-15th of a month its show's 1st of that month which is fetched from the JSON value and if it is after 16th it shows the 16th date of that month from the JSON value.

Well I can check my json value on toast by:

```
if(MY JSON ARRAY.toString().contains(VALUE WHICH I WANT TO COMPARE)){
}
```

But I don't know how to compare the values and show it to `TEXTVIEW`.

This is my JSON:

```
{"result":[{"date":"1 October 2017"},{"date":"1 December 2017"},{"date":"16 
October 2017"},{"date":"16 December 2017"},{"date":"1 October 2017"},
{"date":"16 October 2017"},{"date":"16 December 2017"},{"date":"01 January 
2017"},{"date":"16 December 2017"},{"date":"09 September 2017"}]}
```

This is my code:

```
    // fetch date
    String url = ConfigOfDateMatch.DATA_URL;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            showJSONdate(response);
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(DemoOfCompareDate.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSONdate(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(ConfigOfDateMatch.JSON_ARRAY);
        for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject date = result.getJSONObject(i);

        //from where I got the current date
        String compre = textviewlatestdate1.getText().toString();

        if(result.toString().contains(compre)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes there is a date in this Json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOPE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is how I got my current date in (MONTH IN ALPHABET):

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

//I set my current date to textview
textviewlatestdate1.setText(currentDateandTime);
```

Comment: Can you remove the irrelevant tags

Comment: @Strawberry - what do you mean "irrelevant tag"?

Comment: Well, how's mysql relevant here?